# SAS - Unzip all .gz files in a folder

Tags: sas, zip, gzip, unzip, gunzip

SAS Program - I am trying to unzip all .gz type files in a folder and reading them to a dataset using filename statement. However, I am not able to make it work.

I have .gz files named as follows in a folder:

```
EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_20210701
EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_20210702
EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_20210705
EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_20210706
EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_20210707
.....
.....
EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_20210729
EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_20210730
so on.
```

Note that it does NOT have files for all 31 days in a folder - files are only for business days.
See my code below:

```
/* Change working directory to where all the files are located */
data _null_; 
      rc=dlgcdir("C:\EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_202107");
      put rc=;
   run;

/* using filename statement unzip all files and read them into "f1" */

filename f1 zip EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_202107* gzip lrecl=500; 

/* This code worked when I had the actual name of one of the file - for e.g. "EQY_US_ALL_TRADE_20210702" but does not work when I use the wildcard to run through all of them */
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file names in the folder using the DREAD function, and then a dynamic INFILE statement using the FILEVAR= option to specify the gunzip stream that will be INPUTed from.

Example:

All gzipped files are presumed to be data only and do not contain a header row. The compressed files are all in a single folder and have the .gz file extension

```
data want(keep=filename a b c);
  length folderef $8;
  rc = filename (folderef, 'c:\temp\trade_data');

  did = dopen(folderef);

  do _n_ = 1 to dnum(did);

    filename = dread(did,_n_);
    if scan(filename,-1,'.') ne 'gz' then continue;

    fullname = pathname(folderef) || '/' || filename;

    do while(1);
      infile archive zip filevar=fullname gzip dlm=',' eof=nextfile;
      input a b c;

      OUTPUT;
    end;

nextfile:
  end;

  stop;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks, @Richard. I will try this and let you know, I do have a header row so I will add first obs =2  in infile statement.

Comment: It is actually taking forever and my computer is crashing. Is there any other way to do?

Comment: Surprised to hear it is crashing.  How big are the .gz, how many are there?  Can it process one file? change `dnum(did)` to `1`.  You can also track progress by adding a `putlog fullname=;` before the `do while`.  Perhaps there is one particular file causing trouble.  What does the `input` statement look like ?  You can also try inputting only a single line from each decompression, change the `do while(1)` to `do _i_ = 1 to 1`

Comment: No it is not processing a single file. Its just running and running. There are 21 files in that folder and overall size of the folder is 32 GB.

Comment: data "D:\EQY_US_ALL_TRADES_202107\MainDataset";
rc=filename("folderef","D:\EQY_US_ALL_TRADES_202107");
did = dopen("folderef");
do _n_ = 1 to 1;
filename = dread(did,_n_);
if scan(filename,-1,'.') ne 'gz' then continue;
fullname = pathname("folderef") || '/' || filename;

do _i_ = 1 to 1;
      infile archive zip filevar=fullname gzip dlm='|' firstobs=2 eof=nextfile;
      OUTPUT;
    end;
nextfile:
  end;
  stop;
run;

Proc contents data = "D:\EQY_US_ALL_TRADES_202107\MainDataset";
run;

Comment: Not having an INPUT statement **is not a good thing**.  INPUT is what advances reading through the infile and without it the EOF condition is never reached.

Comment: As a new user you might have the edit feature for your question.  If you *can* edit, add the code you put in the comment in the question